# Django join two tables while keeping ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, connection

Using Django, I am trying to fetch this specific result view from the database using Django:

```
select * from CO2_Low_Adj a JOIN CO2_Low_Metrics b on a.gene_id_B = b.gene_id where a.gene_id_A='Traes_1AL_00A8A2030'
```

I know I can do it using connections, cursor, fetchall and get back a list of dictionaries. However, I am wondering if there is a way to do this in Django while keeping the ORM.

The tables look like this:

```
class Co2LowMetrics(models.Model):
    gene_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=24)
    modular_k = models.FloatField()
    modular_k_rank = models.IntegerField()
    modular_mean_exp_rank = models.IntegerField()
    module = models.IntegerField()
    k = models.FloatField()
    k_rank = models.IntegerField()
    mean_exp = models.FloatField()
    mean_exp_rank = models.IntegerField()
    gene_gene = models.ForeignKey(Co2LowGene, db_column='Gene_gene_id')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'CO2_Low_Metrics'

class Co2LowGene(models.Model):
    gene_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=24)
    entry = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    gene_gene_id = models.CharField(db_column='Gene_gene_id', max_length=24)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'CO2_Low_Gene'

class Co2LowAdj(models.Model):
    gene_id_a = models.CharField(db_column='gene_id_A', max_length=24)  # Field name made lowercase.
    edge_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    gene_id_b = models.CharField(db_column='gene_id_B', max_length=24)  # Field name made lowercase.
    value = models.FloatField()
    gene_gene_id_a = models.ForeignKey('Co2LowGene', db_column='Gene_gene_id_A')  # Field name made lowercase.
    gene_gene_id_b = models.ForeignKey('Co2LowGene', db_column='Gene_gene_id_B')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'CO2_Low_Adj'
```

The database table descriptions are:

```
mysql> describe CO2_Low_Metrics;
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| gene_id               | varchar(24) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| modular_k             | double      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modular_k_rank        | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modular_mean_exp_rank | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| module                | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| k                     | double      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| k_rank                | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| mean_exp              | double      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| mean_exp_rank         | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Gene_gene_id          | varchar(24) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe CO2_Low_Gene;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| gene_id      | varchar(24) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| entry        | int(8)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Gene_gene_id | varchar(24) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe CO2_Low_Adj;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| gene_id_A      | varchar(24) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| edge_number    | int(9)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| gene_id_B      | varchar(24) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value          | double      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Gene_gene_id_A | varchar(24) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Gene_gene_id_B | varchar(24) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Assume that I do not have the ability to change the underlying database schema. That may change and if a suggestion can help in making it easier to use Django's ORM then I can attempt to get it changed.

However, I have been trying to use prefetch_related and select_related but I'm doing something wrong and am not getting everything back right.

With my SQL query I get essentially with the described tables in order CO2_Low_Adj then CO2_Low_Metrics where gene_id_A is the same as gene_gene_id_A ('Traes_1AL_00A8A2030') and gene_id_B is the same as gene_gene_id_B. CO2_Low_Gene does not seem to be used at all with the SQL query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Django does not have a way to perform JOIN queries without foreign keys. This is why `prefetch_related` and `select_related` will not work - they work on foreign keys.

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve. Since your `gene_id` is unique, there will be only one `CO2_Low_Metrics` instance and a list of adj instances:

```
adj = CO2_Low_Adj.objects.filter(gene_id_A='Traes_1AL_00A8A2030') 
metrics = CO2_Low_Metrics.objects.get(pk='Traes_1AL_00A8A2030')
```

and then work on a separate list.

Comment: The query id gets all the adjacency results that contain the query_id in gene_id_a and different gene_ids in gene_id_b. Afterwards, the gene_id_b result is used to query the metrics table. So, I need the results from adjacency to query the results from metrics several times. Something like:
`adj=CO2_Low_Adj.objects.filter(gene_id_A='Traes_1AL_00A8A2030'
metrics = CO2_Low_Metrics.objects.get(pk=adj[0].gene_id_b)`

Then join those together and display that in a table for each result in adj.

Comment: Are you using Django admin or some custom view?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by that, but I'm using django-tables2 to display the list of dictionaries that are generated from the raw sql query.

Unfortunately, that also means no more filtering can be done without the ORM once I have the raw sql query.